# psycopg2: RE-USE of a cursor for a RE-RUN of a SELECT query after doing an UPDATE in between the SELECT queries

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Seeking advise for the best practice to follow for the sequence below using python and psycopg2:

```
(1) Run a select query on "table01"
(2) Update "table01"
(3) Re-run the same select query on "table01"
```

```
conn01 = psycopg2.connect(host=DB_HOST, database=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS)
cursor01 = conn01.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

# (1) first select query
cursor01.execute("SELECT * FROM table01")
set01 = cursor01.fetchall()

# (2) some code in the middle that updates table01 

# (3A) re-run of the same select query
updated_set01 = cursor01.fetchall()
```

Although I have not deleted any rows from non-empty table01, the result of (3A) is empty.

Inserting the following into Step 3 gives the desired result:

```
# (3B) re-run of the same select query
cursor01.execute("SELECT * FROM table01")
updated_set01 = cursor01.fetchall()
```

Is (3B) the re-use of cursor01 the proper procedure? Or, should I create another cursor for the re-run?

Thank you.

Comment: See docs [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) for what the fetch* methods do. Short version, running `fetchall()` 'empties' the cursor, you need to rerun the query to get new results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html, I now understand running `fetchall()` empties the cursor. I shall now use:

```
conn01 = psycopg2.connect(host=DB_HOST, database=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS)
cursor01 = conn01.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

# (1) first select query
cursor01.execute("SELECT * FROM table01")
set01 = cursor01.fetchall()

# (2) some code in the middle that updates table01 

# (3B) re-run of the same select query
cursor01.execute("SELECT * FROM table01")
updated_set01 = cursor01.fetchall()
```

Thank you @AdrianKlaver